# Modsecurity block access from all countries except from a specific IP or specific remote host

Tags: apache2, mod-security, mod-security2

I have the below 3 rules in `modsecurity`.

**Rule 1**: Block all countries defined as high risk except `US`:

```
SecAction \
 "id:900600,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:'tx.high_risk_country_codes = AD AE AF AG AI AL AM AO AQ AR...'"

#Allow only the below countries
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:2000001,drop,msg:'Countries allowed'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@pm US"
```

**Rule 2**: Allow access from the following IP:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$" "phase:1,id:2000002,nolog,allow,msg:'Allow access from IP XX.XX.XX.XX'"
```

**Rule 3**: Allow access from the following remote host:

```
SecRule REMOTE_HOST "host\.name\.com$" "phase:1,id:2000003,nolog,allow,msg:'Allow access from host.name.com'"
```

All rules work well if we take any one of them. However, I'd like to "merge" them into one rule which does the following:

Block all access from the forbidden countries (Rule 1), except when the request comes from IP `XX.XX.XX.XX` (Rule 2) or except when the host is `host.name.com` (Rule 3).

How can I do that in modscurity?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? When you use location based blocking, you only block `amateur` hackers. They are not dangerous. Professionals know how to bypass this type of blacklisting and that is easily done. In other words, why waste your time trying to implement something that will not protect you?

Comment: Note: location-based detection is usually unreliable. The best you will accomplish is to irritate legitimate clients.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Still, there is A LOT of traffic coming from those `amateur` hackers, that I'd like to block. This is once way I can think of. So is it possible? Also, if you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears :)

Comment: Blocking takes additional CPU cycles to accomplish very little. By the time mod_security sees the request, you have already consumed ingress bandwidth (the request has been received through the network stack up to Apache). If a request is arriving without the HTTP `Hosts` header or with the wrong Hosts value, block that traffic as it is always garbage. Next, look into professional-level software firewalls. They will do a much better job than what you can write using Apache rules.

Comment: Thanks for the input John, I will do that. Any software firewall in particular that you'd recommend I should start with?

Comment: I don't have enough information about your environment. Google search for one that fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

CRS Dev-On-Duty here. I think you can achieve your goal with the action [skipAfter](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#skipafter) and a [SecMarker](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#secmarker).

- Add SecMarker BEGIN_IP_CHECK
- Add rule 2 and add skipAfter:END_IP_CHECK to rule 2.
- Add rule 3 and add skipAfter:END_IP_CHECK to rule 3.
- Add rule 1 (which will only be processed when rule 2 and 3 do not match)
- Add SecMarker END_IP_CHECK